# How to exclude certain devices from BLE search query?

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm writing a custom Bluetooth connector and I want the search query to be exact as standard Bluetooth app in mac os. How can I achieve that? I'm using CoreBluetooth and IOBluetooth frameworks to achieve that but getting all kind of devices including TVs and so on.

From the [docs](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services) I understood that there a specific services I want to provide in

```
.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID], options: nil)
```

But what services? I also found the default Xcode bluetooth connector, but it doesn't include source code.

For now my code is:

```
let cbuuids = [CBUUID(string: "0x180A"), CBUUID(string: "0x1801"), CBUUID(string: "0x1800"), CBUUID(string: "0x1812")]

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .poweredOn:
        print("powered on")
        central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: cbuuids, options: nil)
    case .unknown:
        print("state unknown")
    case .resetting:
        print("resetting")
    case .unsupported:
        print("unsupported")
    case .unauthorized:
        print("unauthorized")
    case .poweredOff:
        print("powered off")
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral.name)
    devices.append(peripheral)
    devices = devices.unique

    tableView.reloadData()
    scrubber.reloadData()

}
```

And I'm loading the search query to the touchbar's scrubber, but that's not the point.

Is there any way to match the original devices list in the standard app? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks ok but

`let cbuuids = [CBUUID(string: "0x180A"), CBUUID(string: "0x1801"), CBUUID(string: "0x1800"), CBUUID(string: "0x1812")]`

you are including the default UUIDs such as the **0x180A** is the *device information service*
which i think is included in all device advertisement.

So when you search with this UUID all devices come up in the discovery.
Read More [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services) about the Gatt services

So solution is to only add user defined custom service UUIDs in your search.

Also Note that the UUIDs must be included in the advertisement packets of your device that you are trying to find in the search.
you can read more about Advertisement data [here](https://www.silabs.com/community/wireless/bluetooth/knowledge-base.entry.html/2017/02/10/bluetooth_advertisin-hGsf)